# How to get local storage data to controller with request

Tags: php, laravel-5

Inserted form values to local storage as json.

Then set the data as hidden field before model submission , When I submit the form with serialize ajax, the data not getting in actual json array in Laravel Controller.

I tried json_decode and not working yet.

**Console**

[image]

**Request**

[image]

Comment: What do you get on your server, a string?

Comment: Could you show your code, and print json in browser console (json which is stored in local storage)

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes

Comment: @TaimoorAdilBadshah Updated question. please check

Comment: Could you please show your code snippet.

Comment: check JSON.parse() before submission.

Comment: @TaimoorAdilBadshah  $participants =request('participants')->json();
      dd($participants);

Comment: Make sure, your json data stored in LS is parsed before submitting it. OR decode it twice at server level.

Answer (score 0):

try:
return response()->json(); instead of json_decode.

Comment: "Call to a member function json() on string"

Comment: try `response->json()` instead